# roscore does not initialize

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I'm new to ROS. If I run `roscore`, it does not initialize, it just gets stuck. If I run `strace roscore`, after a certain point, I keep seeing the following forever:

```
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 100000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 100000}) = 0 (Timeout)
```

Concerning the environmental variables, I have:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/filippo/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/filippo/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

The console output is:

```
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://filippo-HP-ENVY-17-Notebook-PC:43155/
ros_comm version 1.12.7


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.7

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [15768]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://filippo-HP-ENVY-17-Notebook-PC:11311/

setting /run_id to 1cc9a0fe-133d-11e7-903f-3423872d9899
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [15781]
started core service [/rosout]
```

Any idea? Thanks a lot :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257898/roscore-does-not-initialize/) by [Filippo Grazioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/29827/filippo-grazioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-03-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-03-27**:
Please show the console output for when you run it too.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-03-27**:
Please edit your question when you have updates. I've added the console output to your question for you.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-27**:
This is what starting up roscore is supposed to do; it will keep running and won't print a new prompt until you stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your roscore has started and is successfully running. That is the same output that I see when I run `roscore`. It is just waiting for an incoming connection.

Now that you've started the ROS `master` using roscore. You need to launch a node. I'd recommend going through the ROS tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure what is wrong, but maybe it would help if you also set the ROS_IP variable

```
export ROS_IP=127.0.0.1
```

---

Originally posted by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) with karma: 351 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1